# How to create System.IO.StreamWriter with Encoding in Powershell?

Tags: .net, powershell, syntax, constructor

I'm trying to create instance of StreamWriter with UTF8 encoding in PowerShell.

```
$f = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter "a.txt", $false, [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
```

This throws error:
New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "StreamWriter" and the argument count: "3".

I'm trying to invoke this constructor:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5f5x7kt(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You're certain you have the correct .Net installed?  Apparently that constructor was introduced in .Net 3.0.

Comment: @DanRayson - Yes. I have newest .NET and from C# application it works great.

Comment: You're sure that $false is a variable named false, and that you're not thinking that you're passing the value false in when in fact you're not?  Sorry for being picky, just want to be sure.

Comment: @DanRayson - $false is of type Boolean when I checked.

Comment: @DanRayson `$false` is an [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-6) and is read-only containing the boolean value false.

Comment: If you're on powershell 5, use the constructor syntax: `$f = [IO.StreamWriter]::new('a.txt', $false, [Text.Encoding]::UTF8)`

Comment: FYI if other encodings than unicode are needed, the function GetEncoding() can be used: `([System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("Windows-1250"))`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Still, I would like to know what is wrong with my original syntax.

**Your original syntax** (fundamentally correctly) uses [*argument* mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing), in which arguments are, loosely speaking, evaluated as follows:

- An argument that doesn't start with either `$`, `(`, or `@` is treated as a *string*, even if not quoted; notably, `[` is *not* among these special characters.

Therefore, **`[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8` is interpreted as a *string literal*** rather than as an expression that returns an `System.Text.Encoding` instance, and no `System.IO.StreamWriter` constructor whose 3rd argument is a *string* can be found.

- Unfortunately, the error message only mentions the *count* of arguments, without indicating that an incorrect *type* might be the cause; this is a known problem - see [GitHub issue #3658](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3658).

The correct solution, as mentioned in a comment by [PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral), is to **enclose `[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8` in `(...)` so as to force its evaluation in *expression* mode**, where it yields the desired result.

Note that the above also implies that the `"..."` (double quotes) around `a.txt` aren't necessary (but do no harm), so we get:

<sup>**Note**: For brevity, I've omitted the initial `System.` components from the full types in the following sample commands; e.g., `IO.StreamWriter` refers to `System.IO.StreamWriter`. Specifying the `System.` part is *optional* in PowerShell in most contexts.</sup>

```bash
$f = New-Object IO.StreamWriter a.txt, $false, ([Text.Encoding]::UTF8)
```

Note that **it is the `,` between the individual constructor arguments that causes them to be passed as an *array* - i.e., a *single argument* - to [`New-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-object)**, where it is (positionally) bound to the array-typed `-ArgumentList` (`-Args`) parameter.
As an aside: passing individual arguments positionally to *separate* parameters is more common, and requires *spaces* to separate them; e.g., `Select-String foo t.txt` is parsed as
`Select-String -Pattern foo -Path t.txt`.

---

Your own answer (since deleted) uses ***pseudo* method syntax** that is **best avoided** and only *happens* to work:

```bash
# AVOID: pseudo method syntax.
$f = New-Object IO.StreamWriter("a.txt", $false, [Text.Encoding]::UTF8)
```

Even though this *looks* like a method call (constructor call), it isn't, and is actually parsed as follows:

```bash
$f = New-Object IO.StreamWriter -ArgumentList ("a.txt", $false, [Text.Encoding]::UTF8)
```

That is, **you've enclosed the original argument array in `(...)`, which causes its elements to be parsed in *expression* mode**, including `[Text.Encoding]::UTF8`, which happened to solve your problem.

Note that - unlike in argument mode - string `a.txt`  *does* have to be enclosed in `"..."` (or `'...'`) in expression mode.

As an aside:

- [`Set-StrictMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode) `-Version 2` or higher, among other things, *prevents* using pseudo-method syntax, but *only* (a) for *two or more* arguments and (b) only if the argument list (`(...)`) follows a *command name* (rather than an *argument*, as in the `New-Object` case), and (c) only if there is *no space* between the command name and the opening `(`; e.g.:
  `& { Set-Strictmode -version 2; foo('a', 'b') }`

---

Note that **PSv5+ *does* offer a *method*-based way to construct objects**, via the **static `new()` method** exposed **on type-information objects**, in which case **all arguments are parsed in *expression* mode**:

```bash
# PowerShell version 5 and above; you can use the ::new() method on types.
$f = [IO.StreamWriter]::new("a.txt", $false, [Text.Encoding]::UTF8)
```

---

A note on **when `[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8`** is needed:

Unlike Window PowerShell, .NET *defaults to* UTF-8 (which PowerShell [Core] (v6+) now does too).

- When you *read* data, you therefore normally don't need to request UTF-8 encoding *explicitly*.
- When you *write* data, **passing `[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8` results in a UTF-8 file *with a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)***, whereas relying on the *default* UTF-8 encoding creates a file *without* a BOM (which is better for cross-platform interoperabiliy); to request a BOM-less encoding explicitly, use `[System.Text.Utf8Encoding]::new()`.

Comment: Thanks for the remark about the BOM. That was exactly the problem we encountered.