# PowerShell: `New-Object` `-ArgumentList` vs calling constructor vs type casting

Tags: powershell

I'm just starting to learn some basics of PowerShell and can't get my head around `New-Object` and type casting. For example this:

```
# all of these yield the same
New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener -ArgumentList 5000
New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener(5000)
[System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener]500  # this works

# all of these yield the same
New-Object -TypeName System.Net.Sockets.TCPClient -ArgumentList "8.8.8.8", 53
New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TCPClient("8.8.8.8", 53)
[System.Net.Sockets.TCPClient]::New("8.8.8.8", 53)
# but this doesn't work
# [System.Net.Sockets.TCPClient]("8.8.8.8", 53) # does not work
```

- What is the difference between using `-ArgumentList` and using `(arg1,...)`? Is it that the name of the type and the `(arg1,...)` are interpreted as two different arguments to `New-Object` even when there is no space between them, and so the `(arg1,...)` is assigned as the value of `-ArgumentList`?
- Why doesn't casting work for the second example of `System.Net.Sockets.TCPClient`? The only difference I see is that it takes multiple arguments, whereas `System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener` takes a single argument. But why can PowerShell cast an integer to a `System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener` but not an array to a `System.Net.Sockets.TCPClient` by calling its constructor? I.e. why aren't these two equivalent:

  - `[System.Net.Sockets.TCPClient]::New("8.8.8.8", 53) # works`
  - `[System.Net.Sockets.TCPClient]("8.8.8.8", 53) # does not work`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the difference between using `-ArgumentList` and using `(arg1, ...)`?

- Do not use `(arg1,...)` it is *pseudo* method syntax that only *happens to work* - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50636061/45375).
- Instead, use `arg1, ...` - no parentheses, whitespace before the list; that is the *positionally implied* equivalent of `-ArgumentList arg1, ...` (or `-Args arg1, ...`)

> Why doesn't casting work for the second example of `System.Net.Sockets.TCPClient`?

Casting only works in two variants:

- With a *scalar* that matches a single-argument constructor or, in the case of a *string*, if the target type has a static `.Parse()` method.
- With a [*hash table*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) (`@{ ... }`) whose entries' keys match properties of the target type *and* assuming that the target type has a parameterless public constructor.

Therefore you cannot cast from an *array* of values.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63982452/45375) for more information.