# Convert a string in PowerShell (in Europe) to UTF-8

Tags: string, powershell, utf-8, oledbconnection

For a REST call I need the German "Stück" in UTF-8 as read from an access database with

```
$conn = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=$filename;Persist Security Info=False;")
```

and try to convert it.
I have found out that PowerShell ISE seems to encode string constants in ANSI.
So I tried as a minimum test without database and got the same result:

```
$Text1 = "Stück" # entered via ISE, this is also what I get from the database
# ($StringFromDatabase -eq $Test1) shows $true

$enc = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes($Text1)
# also tried [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1") # = 28591

$Text1 = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($enc)

$Text1
$Text1 = "StÃ¼ck" # = UTF-8, entered here with Notepad++, encoding set to UTF-8
"must see: $Text1"
```

So I get two outputs - the converted one (showing "St?ck") but I need to see "StÃ¼ck".

Comment: You've got it backwards - sounds like you want `UTF.GetBytes($Text1)` and then back to `ASCII.GetString($enc)`

Comment: As an aside: The PowerShell ISE is [no longer actively developed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise#support) and [there are reasons not to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375) (bottom section), notably not being able to run PowerShell (Core) 6+. The actively developed, cross-platform editor that offers the best PowerShell development experience is [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with its [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell).

Comment: As an aside: Please avoid pseudo method syntax: instead of `New-Object SomeType(arg1, ...)`, use `New-Object SomeType [-ArgumentList] arg1, ...` - PowerShell cmdlets, scripts and functions are invoked like _shell commands_, not like _methods_. That is, no parentheses around the argument list, and _whitespace_-separated arguments (`,` constructs an _array_ as a _single argument_, as needed for `-ArgumentList`). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50636061/45375)

Comment: @mklement0 Thank you for the hint with ISE problems. Locally I am using Visual Studio 2019 and VS Code but edit/run the currently mentioned script on a customer system within ISE in TeamViewer co-working sessions without any problems. But good to know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> that PowerShell ISE seems to encode string constants in **ANSI**.

That **only applies when communicating with *external programs***, whereas you're using in-process .NET APIs.

<sup>As an aside: this discrepancy with regular console windows, which use the active *OEM* code page is one of the reasons that make the obsolescent ISE problematic - see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375) for more information.</sup>

**String literals *in memory* are always .NET strings, which are UTF-16-encoded (composed of 16-bit Unicode code units), capable of representing *all* Unicode characters**.<sup>[1]</sup>

---

##### Character encoding in *web-service calls* ([`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod), [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest)):

To *send* UTF-8 strings, specify `charset=utf-8` as part of the `-ContentType` argument; e.g.:

```sh
Invoke-RestMethod -ContentType 'text/plain; charset=utf-8' ...
```

On *receiving* strings, PowerShell automatically decodes them either based on an explicitly specified `charset` field (character encoding) in the response's content header or, in its absence using ISO-8859-1 (which is closely related to, but in effect a *subset* of Windows-1252).

- If a given response doesn't specify a `charset` but in actually uses a *different* encoding from ISO-8859-1 - say UTF-8 - PowerShell will *misinterpret* the strings received, which requires *re-encoding* after the fact - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53034595/45375).

---

##### Character encoding when communicating with *external programs*:

If you need to send a string with a particular encoding to an external program (via the pipeline, which the target program receives via stdin), set the [`$OutputEncoding` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#outputencoding) to that encoding, and PowerShell will automatically convert your .NET strings to the specified encoding.

**To send UTF-8-encoded strings to external programs via the pipeline**:

```sh
$OutputEncoding = [System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new()
```

Note, however, that this alone isn't sufficient in order to correctly *receive* UTF-8 output from external programs; for that, you need to set `[Console]::OutputEncoding` to the same encoding.

**To make your PowerShell session fully UTF-8-aware** (irrespective of whether in the ISE or a regular console window):

```sh
# Needed in the ISE only:
chcp >$null # Dummy console-program call that ensures that a console is allocated.

# Set all encodings relevant to communicating with external programs to UTF-8.
$OutputEncoding = [Console]::InputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding =
  [System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new()
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49481797/45375) for more information.

---

<sup>[1] Note, however, that Unicode characters with a code point greater than `0xFFFF`, i.e. those outside the so-called BMP (Basic Multilingual Plane), must be represented with *two* 16-bit code units (`[char]`), namely so-called *surrogate pairs*.</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much. The trick was to add the content type in both the header and as additional parameter in **Invoke-RestMethod**.
I already used in my `function CheckAccessToken([ref]$expires, [ref]$headers): ... $headers.Value = @{ ... "Content-type" = "application/json; charset=UTF-8" Accept = "application/json" }` and called `$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $productUrl -Method Patch -Headers $headers -Body $body` but had to add `-ContentType "application/json; charset=UTF-8"` there. Thank you so much again :-).