# How to execute SqlCommand in PowerShell?

Tags: .net, powershell, ado.net

I'm getting the following exception:

> New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "SqlCommand" and the argument
> count: "2". At
> C:\Users\aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaps.ARMTemplate\CoreDbScripts\RunSqlScripts.ps1:128
> char:19
>
> - ...     $comm = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand( $file,$conn) ...
> - ```
>               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   ```
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

Here's my code:

```
Using-Object ($conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection $connString) {
    $conn.Open();
    
    Using-Object ($tran = $conn.BeginTransaction) {
        foreach ($file in $sqlFiles)
        {
          Write-Host "file: " $file.Name
          $comm = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($file, $conn);
          $comm.Transaction = $tran
        [void]$comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
        }
        $tran.Commit();
    };
};
```

What am I doing wrong? How do we execute the `SqlCommand`?

Comment: As an aside: It's best to pseudo method syntax: Instead of `New-Object SomeType(arg1, ...)`, use `New-Object SomeType [-ArgumentList] arg1, ...` - PowerShell cmdlets, scripts and functions are invoked like _shell commands_, not like _methods_. That is, no parentheses around the argument list, and _whitespace_-separated arguments (`,` constructs an _array_ as a _single argument_, as needed for `-ArgumentList`). However, method syntax _is_ required if you use the PSv5+ `[SomeType]::new()` constructor-call method. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50636061/45375)

Answer (score 3):

The error message implies that **at least one of the constructor arguments you're passing is of the *wrong data type*** (given that it isn't the *number* of arguments that is the problem).

The [two-argument constructor of class `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.-ctor#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlCommand__ctor_System_String_System_Data_SqlClient_SqlConnection_) you're trying to call has the following signature:

```cs
public SqlCommand (string cmdText, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection connection);
```

By contrast, your code suggests that **you're passing an instance of type [`System.IO.FileInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo) as the first argument**, i.e. an object describing a file as a file-system entry.
**Instead, pass the file's *content***, which you can obtain in full via [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) `-Raw`:

```sh
$comm = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand ($file | Get-Content -Raw), $conn
```

Or, using the alternative PSv5+ syntax for invoking constructors, via the [intrinsic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members) static `::new()` method PowerShell makes available on types:

```sh
$comm = [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand]::new(($file | Get-Content -Raw), $conn)
```

Comment: + ... ata.SqlClient.SqlCommand (Get-Content -Raw $filesconcatenated), $conn
+                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (
/****** Object:String) [Get-Content], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand

Comment: As stated, the assumption is that `$file` is a single `FileInfo` instance (and that it refers to an existing file containing SQL commands).  I don't know what `$filesconcatenated` is, but it doesn't sound like a single `FileInfo` instance.

Comment: @AlexGordon, however, I just realized that in Windows PowerShell (no longer in PowerShell Core) `Get-Content -Raw $file` can _situationally_ fail (depending on how the `FileInfo` instance was obtained, it may stringify to the _mere file name_ rather than the _full path_), so I've updated the answer to use the robust `$file | Get-Content -Raw`

Comment: P.S., @AlexGordon: If you do want to _merge_ the content of _multiple_ files and pass that as a single string, use `(($sqlFiles | Get-Content -Raw) -join "\`n")`

Comment: @AlexGordon, looking at your previous questions suggests that `$filesconcatenated` may already be the merged content from multiple files, in which case you don't need `Get-Content` and can pass the value as-is - assuming that it is a _single_ string. In essence, testing the first argument with `-is [string]` must return `$true`, and `-is [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection]` must be `$true` for the second one in order for the constructor call to succeed. Let's try to bring closure to this and some of your previous questions: Please accept answers or provide feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I see quite a few examples here suggesting `Using-Object` but that's custom function (see some of the other SO pages) to simulate the `using()` block in C#. Powershell doesn't have that. You simply need to declare the SqlConnection and SqlCommand objects as an objects. Don't forget to dispose of them. I strongly recommend a try-catch-finally block, and be sure to dispose of the SqlConnection object in the `finally` block.

I think you're looking for this. (Warning: I didn't run test this, but it's very close):

```
try
{
  $conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($ConnectionString)
  $conn.Open();
  $tran = $conn.BeginTransaction()
  foreach ($file in $sqlFiles)
  {
    Write-Host "file: " $file.Name
    $comm = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($file, $conn);
    $comm.Transaction = $tran
    [void]$comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
    $comm.Dispose()
  }
  $tran.Commit()
}
catch
{
  # Handle your error here.
}
finally
{
  # Make sure the SQL connection closes.
  $conn.Dispose()
}
```