# Powershell script unable to decrypt password from Jenkins withCredentials()

Tags: powershell, jenkins, db2, credentials

I created a powershell script to run DB2 queries in Jenkins

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'cred-id', usernameVariable: 'ID', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD')]) {
    $cn = new-object system.data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Server=Server; Provider=IBMDADB2;DSN=DBName;User Id=$ID;Password=$PASSWORD");
    $ds = new-object "System.Data.DataSet" "ds"
    $q = "myQuery"
    $da = new-object "System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter" ($q, $cn)
    $da.Fill($ds) 
    $cn.close()
}
```

If I run the script and hard code my credentials, it run fine.

With withCredentials(), I am getting the following error: **`Security processing failed with reason "15" ("PROCESSING FAILURE")`**

From some research, the error seems to be because DB2 can't handle encrypted data. Is there a way to overcome this error?

EDIT:
I tried to add

```
$SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $PASSWORD -AsPlainText -Force
$BSTR = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($SecurePassword)
$UnsecurePassword = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)
```

at the beginning of my powershell script, but it still throws the same error even though the credential work fine if used in plain text

Comment: As an aside: It's best to pseudo method syntax: Instead of `New-Object SomeType(arg1, ...)`, use `New-Object SomeType [-ArgumentList] arg1, ...` - PowerShell cmdlets, scripts and functions are invoked like _shell commands_, not like _methods_. That is, no parentheses around the argument list, and _whitespace_-separated arguments (`,` constructs an _array_ as a _single argument_, as needed for `-ArgumentList`). However, method syntax _is_ required if you use the PSv5+ `[SomeType]::new()` constructor-call method. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50636061/45375)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the docs for the [Credentials Binding Jenkins plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/) correctly, the variables designated in the `withCredentials()` call become *environment* variables, so as to enable their use across process boundaries.
Note that the values of these environment variables are *not* encrypted, so no extra (decryption) effort is required on the part of the target process.

Therefore, you need to use `$env:`<sup>[1]</sup> instead of just `$` to refer to these variables in PowerShell:

```
$cn = new-object system.data.OleDb.OleDbConnection "Server=Server; Provider=IBMDADB2;DSN=DBName;User Id=$env:ID;Password=$env:PASSWORD"
```

---

<sup>[1] See the conceptual [about_Environment_Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Environment_Variables) help topic.</sup>