# Unable to connect-AZAccount in Azure Automation with a Service Principal

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-automation

I have an Azure Automation Runbook that needs to Connect-AzAccount to export a CSV from the Automation Account to a Blob Storage Account. My Service Principal has an ApplicationID and a Secret. per the documentation for Connect-AzAccount -Credential can accept this.

However when I attempt to feed it in via:

```
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($ApplicationID, $AppSecret)
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $TenantId -Credential $Credential
```

I get the following error:

Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Credential' because it is null

Would anyone be able to point me to where I am messing up?

Comment: In your code, the only scenario in which this error would occur is if `$Credential` is indeed `$null`, which in turn would only occur if the `New-Object` call failed silently (which it wouldn't by default).

Comment: After running it again there is more to the error.
```Cannot find overload for "PSCredential" and the argument count: "2". ```

Comment: `$AppSecret` must be a  `[securestring]` instance for the `System.Management.Automation.PSCredential` constructor call to succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**

Since the *root* cause turned out to be the following error:

> `Cannot find overload for "PSCredential" and the argument count: "2".`

the implication is that **the `$AppSecret` argument in your `New-Object -TypeName PSCredential` call was *not* of type [`[securestring]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Security.SecureString)**, which is what the [relevant `[pscredential]` constructor overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscredential.-ctor#system-management-automation-pscredential-ctor(system-string-system-security-securestring)) requires.

Making it a `[securestring]` instance solved your problem.

---

A `[securestring]` instance can be constructed or obtained in several ways:

- Preferably, load the secret from a secrets-management system, such as the [`Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretManagement`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.secretmanagement/?view=ps-modules) module, which supports various extension modules implementing *vaults* (secrets stores), such as [`Microsoft.PowerShell.SecretStore`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.secretstore/?view=ps-modules) for local file-system storage and the [`Az.KeyVault`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az.KeyVault) module for retrieving secrets from an Azure Key Vault.
- [Not advisable for security reasons] Use [`ConvertTo-SecureString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/convertto-securestring) `-AsPlainText` to convert a plain-text representation of the secret to a `[securestring]`.

Alternatively, you could obtain the entire `[pscredential]` instance differently:

- *Interactively*, via [`Get-Credential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-credential):

  ```bash
  # Prompts for the app secret (password) and returns a [pscredential] instance.
  $Credential = Get-Credential $ApplicationID
  ```
- On Windows only, import a `[pscredential]` instance that was previously persisted to a *file* with [`Export-Clixml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-clixml) with [`Import-Clixml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-clixml) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40029496/45375).

A general caveat: `[securestring]` offers *limited* security on Windows, and *virtually none* on Unix-like platforms, where encryption isn't even employed - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60406968/45375).

---

As for **what you tried** and the **error message** you saw:

> `New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($ApplicationID, $AppSecret)`

This command can be simplified to:

```bash
New-Object pscredential $ApplicationID, $AppSecret
# Short for:
#  New-Object -TypeName pscredential -ArgumentList $ApplicationID, $AppSecret
```

Note:

- The use of short name `pscredential`, given that it is a [type accelerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Type_Accelerators) for the full type name, [`System.Management.Automation.PSCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.PSCredential).
- The absence of `(...)` around the arguments, as that amounts to *pseudo method syntax* that is best avoided - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50636061/45375).

`New-Object` calls translate into .NET *constructor* calls, and in PowerShell 5 and above there's now a a **more direct way to call constructors, using the static `::new()` method** exposed by PowerShell on *types*. Therefore, the equivalent of the command above is:

```bash
# PSv5+ equivalent of the above.
# Note that this syntax *does* require method-call syntax.
[pscredential]::new($ApplicationID, $AppSecret)
```

The advantage of this approach is that you can **easily inspect the constructor *overloads*** (variants with different parameters), simply by **accessing `::new` *without the `(...)` part***:

```bash
# Print constructor overloads
[pscredential]::new
```

Output:

```
OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
pscredential new(string userName, securestring password)
pscredential new(psobject pso)
```

The first overload - the only one to accept *two* arguments - also reveals the parameter *types*, and indeed shows that the second parameter requires a `[securestring]` instance as its argument.

Unfortunately, the ***error message* you get when the *count* of arguments is correct but the *type* isn't is *somewhat misleading***:

> `Cannot find overload for "PSCredential" and the argument count: "2".`

Clearly, you *did* pass *2* arguments, but it was the fact that the 2nd argument had the *wrong type* that triggered the error, whereas the message makes it sound like you passed the wrong *number* of arguments.

Improving this error message has been green-lit in [GitHub issue #3658](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3658), but so far no one has stepped up to implement it.